# How to add tags in the maven goal in azure pipeline yaml file

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cucumber-jvm

I need to add a maven goal in azure pipeline yaml file which contains @tag, when i do so it is throwing some error saying @ is not allowed.

mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags '~@skip_scenario and @Regression'"

this is the goal i need to add in the yaml file

YAML:
trigger:

- master

pool:
vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
  mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
  mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
  javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
  jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
  jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
  publishJUnitResults: true
  testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
  goals: 'test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Smoke"'

Error:
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "@Smoke"". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the `@is not allowed` issue. I tried to add this command in the Maven task -> Goals field and it could run successfully. Do you see this problem during the run pipeline or in the Build log. You could share the yaml task definition you used to run this command.

Comment: - task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Smoke"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test with the Yaml and I could reproduce it.

The cause of this issue is that the `goals` field in the Maven task doesn't support the command.

According to [this doc](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#a-build-lifecycle-is-made-up-of-phases):

The Lifecycle contains validate,compile,test, package,verify ,install, deploy.

The command you used to add tags is the  Maven command-line. You could add the command in the `Option` field.

For example:

```
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'test'
    options: 'test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Smoke"'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

Here is the doc about [the Maven task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops#arguments).

Hope this helps.